# Android using custom theme to change actionbar logo's size

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Is this possible?

Is there an item in my custom theme xml that I can change the size and margin of the app logo that appears on the top left?

Answer (score 0):

well, when you browse the SDK's content, more specifically android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-16\data\res\layout (I'm on Windows), look at the file called screen.xml. That is the layout for a default application screen. You could change this as use it in your project instead of the default layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- This is the basic layout for a screen, with all of its features enabled. -->

    <!-- Title bar and content -->
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Popout bar for action modes -->
    <ViewStub android:id="@+id/action_mode_bar_stub"
          android:inflatedId="@+id/action_mode_bar"
          android:layout="@layout/action_mode_bar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Title bar -->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@android:id/title_container"
        style="?android:attr/windowTitleBackgroundStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/windowTitleSize">

    <ImageView android:id="@android:id/left_icon"
        android:layout_width="16dip"
        android:layout_height="16dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+android:id/right_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >
        <ImageView android:id="@android:id/right_icon"
            android:layout_width="16dip"
            android:layout_height="16dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />
        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_circular"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmallTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:max="10000"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_horizontal"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@android:id/right_container"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@android:id/left_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:max="10000"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
        style="?android:attr/windowTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@android:id/right_container"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/left_icon"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Content -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:foregroundGravity="fill_horizontal|top"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/windowContentOverlay"
/>
```